# Extraction of Sub-string on various delimiters

Tags: java, android, regex

I am new to android. I need to extract various sub strings from a string in my application.
That extraction of sub-strings are depends on various and different delimiters and combination of that.

The pattern of string delimiters is like :

```
xxx|xxx|#yyy|ww~aaaaa|ww~ii|ww~t|*|yyy
```

Now i need to get all xxx, yyy, ww, ii, t from the strings by using all symbols as delimiters.
There is a huge string from which above shown is the part of string. Rest is repeating as above and makes a large string.

So how to do this.

Thank you.

Comment: "Reply as soon as possible".  Sounds very rude.  Everyone here is a volunteer. Someone will answer if they can, when they have the time.

Comment: Show us what you have tried as soon as possible.

Comment: try using regex http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string.split("\\W+")
```

will work for you.

Here, `\W` means a `non-alphanumeric character`.

`+` means `one or more than one`.